# Xlwings ExitCode

Tags: python, excel, vba

I'm working with **xlwings** now and have a problem on running VBA code to connect to Python. I encounter the error message: `Run-time error '6': flow`, which breaks at the line:

```
ExitCode = Wsh.Run("cmd.exe /C " & DriveCommand & _RunCommand & _
                   """" & WORKBOOK_FULLNAME & """ ""from_xl""" & " " & Chr(34) & _
                   Application.path & "\" & Application.Name & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & Application.Hwnd & Chr(34) & _
                   " 2> """ & LOG_FILE & """ ", _
                   WindowStyle, WaitOnReturn)
```

**The value in the brackets** -

```
"cmd.exe /C python -B -c "import sys, os; sys.path.extend(os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'path_to_folder;')).split(';')); import fibonacci; fibonacci.xl_fibonacci()" ""path_to_xlsm" "from_xl" "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\Microsoft Excel" "3869396" 2> "C:\path\AppData\Roaming\xlwings.log" "
```

I appreciate any ideas on the problem. Thanks!